# How do I plot a bar graph from matplotlib/seaborn with an int list as value and a string list as x axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a list of ints `arr=[1,2,3,4]` and a list of strings `list(df)` (which returns a list of column headers of the dataframe). I want to plot a bar graph such that the x axis labels are taken from the list of strings and the value for them are taken from the list of ints.

So for eg if list(df) returns [a,b,c,d], there would be a graph with markings of a,b,c,d on the x axis having a corresponding value of 1,2,3,4 respectively on the y axis.

I can't figure out a way to do that. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like an intuitive thing to do. I followed the example [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) to create this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vals=[1,2,3,4,5]
inds=range(len(vals))
labels=["A","B","C","D","E"]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
rects = ax.bar(inds, vals)
ax.set_xticks([ind+0.5 for ind in inds])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

and get this output:

[image]

In the first half of the code I'm just setting up the variables.
In the second half I call plt.subplots() so I can get the axis (ax) handle to put the tickmarks in as well as the rects. Setting the tickmarks determines where the labels will be, so I shifted them by 0.5 to the right, otherwise they would be at the leftmost edge of each box.

Comment: @riberman thanks a ton man! just another query. the xticklabels (like A, B, C... here) are long column names and they overlap over each other. Is there any way to print them in a readable way?

Comment: `locs, labels = plt.xticks(); plt.setp(labels, rotation=45)`

Comment: can anyone tell me why @rbierman's solution doesn't work on my case? I have the following two lists: `weekday_with_hosts: [u'Tue', u'Thu', u'Sat', u'Sun', u'Fri', u'Mon', u'Wed']
hosts: [277840, 363436, 184380, 182590, 263086, 301684, 318698]` and I got error: `could not convert string to float: Tue`

Comment: @mdivk I tried your code and it worked for me, I think you might be making the mistake of setting the `weekday_with_hosts` as the `vals` and `hosts` as the `labels` instead of the other way around.